# How do i create a slanted middle border with two tabs

Tags: css, tabs, border

I have two toggled tabs each with 50% width. Both are clickable tabs. The middle border of the tabs needs to be slanted. I tried with skew property. But the text inside the tab is also getting skewed.   How do i achieve a slanted middle border. Is there anyway to achieve with just css borders ?

```
.toggleBtnRight {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'Futura LT BOLD' !important;
    color: #005695;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
.toggleBtnLeft {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'Futura LT BOLD' !important;
    color: #005695;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}




   .clickedBtn { 
background: #f3f3f5 !important; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c7 !important; 
border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c7 !important;
 border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c7 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Forgot to add the style for 

.clickedBtn {
 background: #f3f3f5 !important;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c7 !important;
 border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c7 !important;
 border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c7 !important;
  
}

Comment: you can edit your own post. just add the above commented styles in your question

Comment: Ok. I have edited. Is my question going to be answered?

Comment: Maybe you could use a white coloured `<span>` with height or 1px to make the boarder and apply the CSS property `transform: rotate(Xdeg);` to slant it by the amount you want?

Comment: But my entire div will get rotated if i use rotate . I just need to slightly slant  the middle border towards the left that is used between the two tabs.

Comment: @kate So you would need to apply the CSS rotate property specifically to the `<span>` as opposed to the entire div that makes up the tab.

Comment: @kate I would offer an example JSFiddle of this possible solution but your question provides no HTML markup for me to use

Comment: Look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/wahc14Lm/3/) and tell me if this is sort of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding some psuedo element like `:before` and add background and borders in it make `transforms` in that element like

```
.toggleBtnRight:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border: .1em solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: none;
    /* border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,229,229,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
    transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

for more details have a look at the [demo](https://codepen.io/niklakhani/pen/yyapdR)